Azure Service Bus Topic trigger function not listening service bus message continuously when isSessionEnable=false
We are facing issue in Azure Service Bus topic trigger 8.0 isolation runtime when we add IsSessionEnabled=false. process the message but after process all message to goes idle and not pick other service bus message automatically
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "subscription", Connection = "TopicConnectionString",AutoCompleteMessages =false,IsBatched =true,IsSessionEnabled=false)]
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages,
    ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
{  
// message processing

// we are concatenating message to blob storage csv file.
}

We want is process all message automatically on regular basis.


We are facing issue in Azure Service Bus topic trigger 8.0 isolation runtime when we add IsSessionEnabled=false. process the message but after process all message to goes idle and not pick other service bus message automatically

In order to avoid this, you can consider creating the function app in App Service plan.
In App Service plan navigate to Configuration -> General Settings then turn on Always on.


In consumption plan, host stops after being idle for 20min. You can check this in the associated application insight.


